# Do something when content is fully loaded via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, load

I'm loading the content of a div via ajax, using this:

```
function loadContent( url ) {
 jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(data) 
        {           
          // set content
          jQuery("#overlayDiv").html(data);

          // hide loading spinner
          jQuery("#overlayCleared").hide();
        }
      });
```

}

The problem is that I want to do something (hide the loading spinner) after 'data', containing images and so on, has loaded completely! How can this be done?

Thank you!..

Comment: Images and so on... Is it just images? or do you have flash elements or something like that as well there?

Comment: what exactly do you want to do while the data is getting loaded may be there is an easy way of it .

Comment: what you wrote there should work actually. 
Does the loading Spinner not hide at all or does it hide before the data is fully loaded?

Answer (score 1):

You should do somehting like this in the success

```
var images = jQuery('#content img');
images.load(function() {
   console.log(loading images has been completed);
});
```

try this plugin also

https://github.com/peol/jquery.imgloaded/raw/master/ahpi.imgload.js

Answer (score 0):

If `data` is html, then I think a solution would be to use an `iframe` as the content container. Instead of the ajax call just change the src of the `iframe` and add a `.load(..)` handler which will fire after all content is loaded.